# Excel Formula - If Cell A1 is Y, then Cell B10 should say YES

Tags: excel

Done a search on here, but cant find the formula I need (found bits that help me with the IF statement)

Using Excel 2007

In Cell A1,    I either enter the Letter:    P   or   F

In cell B10, I want an "IF" command to say:   If cell A1 = P , then display  PASS    , if cell A1 = F  , then display FAIL

Is that an easy formula ?  I can get it to show Pass, but don't know how to add on the 2nd If ?!!

Also, is there a way to use conditional formatting in the same command..

IE:
if cell A1 = P  ,  then display  PASS and change cell to Green...

If cell A1 = F  , then  display FAIL, and change cell to RED.....

IF CELL A1=P AND Cell B1=Y, then display PASS w/ REM, and change cell to Amber

Cheers

Comment: Please read : [tour] and [ask]

Comment: Press F1, type "if", hit enter!

Comment: In the cell B10 `=IF(A1="P","Pass",IF(A1="F","Fail","Undefined"))`, then the conditional formatting is as basic as conditional formatting gets, look it up in the help or just click through the menu "Conditional formatting > Highlight Rules > Text that contains > ..."

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and yes, did start to read "how to post" before I posted).....

I did the F1 in excel first, but got stuck with doing the 2nd  IF  command....  and as much as I can do conditional formatting, its adding that command onto the Formula I am stuck with....

Thank you for the reply though :)

Answer (score 0):

Formula:

```
=IF(A1="P", "Pass", IF(A1="F", "FAIL", ""))
```

Custom conditional formatting rule:

```
=B10="Fail"
```

Set red and apply to B10. New rule:

```
=B10="Pass"
```

Set green and apply to B10.

**EDIT**

As per your comment ill explain the formula

```
=IF(A1="P", IF(B1="Y", "Pass-1", "P"), IF(A1="F, "Fail", ""))
```

First condition is if `A1="P"`
**1st outcome**
If true, it checks `B1="Y"`. If that **does**, display `Pass-1`, if it **does not**, then `A1` has still equaled `P`, so it displays `Pass`.
**2nd Outcome**
If `A1` does **not** equal `P` from the first condition, then it checks if `A1="F"`, which if true displays `Fail`, and if **not**, leave the cell blank.

Comment: thank you kindly! :)
I did some more reading, trial and error stuff, got there in the end :)
However, what I am stuck with now, is trying to add a 3rd query....

if cell A1 = P , then display PASS and change cell to Green...

If cell A1 = F , then display FAIL, and change cell to RED.....

If cell A1 = P & Cell B1 = Y , then display PASS-1  , and change colour to Amber..

I have the colours sorted, so its just the question of can you have 2 IF commands produce the 1 result ?

Comment: You can keep nesting `IF`'s till your hearts content. `=IF(A1="P", IF(B1="Y", "Pass-1", "P"), IF(A1="F, "Fail", ""))`

Comment: Cheers for reply..
cant get it to work:...........................     If Cell A1 has "P" and Cell B1 has "Y" , I need cell B10 to show  "PASS-1".....
IE:  the command is looking at 2 cells.

Comment: Am guessing you can't have an IF command that can read 2 Cell entries to output a Result ??

Comment: You can use `AND` to check multiple conditions, but as you have two conditions for `A1` either Pass, or Pass-1 dependent on `B1`, its better to check `A1` first, then check `B1` after. I will update the answer explaining what is happening.

Comment: You could use `=IF(AND(A1="P", B1="Y"), value if true, value if false` but if false, you still have to check `A1` again, which is unnecessary when you can do it with nested `IF`s instead.

Comment: Thank you kindly :)